# how to resize my image preview for website

Tags: html, embed, web-development-server

Hi I'm using the below code to setup a image preview

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`
`<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/VjUU72S.png" width="1200" height="600"/>`

It sets up the preview for the link sent but it is really small (see image below)

[image: This is the image preview on discord]

However I want it to be alot bigger like the below image

[image: This is Githubs Example]

How can i achieve this? ive already tried to do the below

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/VjUU72S.png" width="1200" height="600"/>`

The actual image size is '1200x600'

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution for this and achieved my goal.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="description" content="Im Danial Ahmed and this is my personal 
website">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://imgur.com/DaUY6vk.png">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://imgur.com/DaUY6vk.png">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@unofficialdxnny">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="unofficialdxnny (Danial Ahmed) 
index.html">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Im Danial Ahmed and this is my 
personal website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://imgur.com/DaUY6vk.png">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Im Danial Ahmed and this is my 
personal website">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="unofficialdxnny">
<meta property="og:type" content="object">
<meta property="og:title" content="unofficialdxnny (Danial Ahmed) Website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://unofficialdxnny.netlify.app">
<meta property="og:description" content="Im Danial Ahmed and this is my 
personal website">
<meta name="expected-hostname" 
content="https://unofficialdxnny.netlify.app/">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1167ab">
```

Answer (score -1):

Discord relies on the meta tag of **twitter cards** to render image sizes. More info on [twitter website](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image)

So, just add this in your head :

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

Comment: hi so this didnt really work. its got no preview now

Comment: Also put width and height in separate tags like this instead of putting them in `og:image` : 
```html
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600" />
```

In any case, adding twitter meta tag should not break image preview.